# Python Domain Finder

Tags: python, algorithm, url, web-deployment

```
import re

# country domain listed
myInput = "ac ad ae af ag ai al am an ao aq ar as at au aw ax az ba bb bd be bf bg bh bi bj bl bm bn bo br bq bs bt bv bw by bz ca cc cd cf cg ch ci ck cl cm cn co cr cs cu cv cw cx cy cz dd de dj dk dm do dz ec ee eg eh er es et eu fi fj fk fm fo fr ga gb gd ge gf gg gh gi gl gm gn gp gq gr gs gt gu gw gy hk hm hn hr ht hu id ie il im in io iq ir is it je jm jo jp ke kg kh ki km kn kp kr kw ky kz la lb lc li lk lr ls lt lu lv ly ma mc md me mf mg mh mk ml mm mn mo mp mq mr ms mt mu mv mw mx my mz na nc ne nf ng ni nl no np nr nu nz om pa pe pf pg ph pk pl pm pn pr ps pt pw py qa re ro rs ru rw sa sb sc sd se sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sr ss st su sv sx sy sz tc td tf tg th tj tk tl tm tn to tp tr tt tv tw tz ua ug uk um us uy uz va vc ve vg vi vn vu wf ws ye yt yu za zm zr zw"

#List create by spliting myInput string with space
myList = myInput.split(" ")


#Taking user input for phrase
userInputString = input("{}Enter a phrase, and we'll try to find some URLs that match: " .format('\n')).lower()

#Using regex substitution to remove whitespace and special characters
updatedUserInput = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+','',userInputString)

# print(updatedUserInput)

userInputLength = len(updatedUserInput)

while( userInputLength > 2 ):
    
    currentDomain = updatedUserInput[userInputLength-2:userInputLength]

    if(userInputLength == len(updatedUserInput)):
        leftOverPath = ''
    else:
        leftOverPath = updatedUserInput[userInputLength+1:]
    
    if currentDomain in myList:
        print(updatedUserInput[:userInputLength-2]+"."+currentDomain+"/"+leftOverPath)
        userInputLength -= 1
    else:
        userInputLength -= 1
```

When I provide a string input as "Video game name"

**Expected Output is**

- videogamena.me
- videogamen.am/e
- videogame.na/me
- videoga.me/name
- videog.am/ename
- video.ga/mename
- vi.de/ogamename
- v.id/eogamename

**Actual Output is**

```
videogamena.me/
videogamen.am/
videogame.na/e
videoga.me/ame
videog.am/name
video.ga/ename
vi.de/gamename
v.id/ogamename
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Tried any debugging yet? What were your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like correct a pice of code :)
Just quick view, your `leftOverPath` missing on character. Can check bellow of code for answer. Btw, please use `snake_case` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) when coding python. Thanks

```
while (userInputLength > 2):
    currentDomain = updatedUserInput[userInputLength - 2:userInputLength]
    leftOverPath = updatedUserInput[userInputLength:]
    leftOverPath = "/" + leftOverPath if leftOverPath else leftOverPath
    if currentDomain in myList:
        print(updatedUserInput[:userInputLength - 2] + "." + currentDomain + leftOverPath)
    userInputLength -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I missed that. And yes snake_case will be used from now.